# How to implement generics in C# interfaces?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Hi I am trying to implement Generics in C# interfaces. I have one method which should take different models as parameters after implementing Generics. Below is my Interface.

```
 public interface IKafkaProducer<T>
  {
    Task ProduceAsync(T kafkaEvent, string topicName);
  }
```

This Kafka event may should be different models after implementing Generics. For example It should be able to take Employee or User class etc. Below is my class implementation.

```
public class KafkaProducer<T> : IKafkaProducer<T>
  {
   public async Task ProduceAsync(T kafkaEvent, string topicName)
    {
      using (var schemaRegistry = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(this.kafkaSchemaRegistryConfig.GetConfig()))
      using (var producer =
               new ProducerBuilder<string, ProductRangeEvent>(this.producerConfigFactory.ProducerConfig())
                   .SetKeySerializer(new AvroSerializer<string>(schemaRegistry))
                   .SetValueSerializer(new AvroSerializer<ProductRangeEvent>(schemaRegistry))
                   .Build())
      {
        Console.WriteLine($"{producer.Name} producing on {topicName}. Enter user names, q to exit.");
        await producer
              .ProduceAsync(topicName, new Message<string, ProductRangeEvent> { Key = null, Value = kafkaEvent })
              .ContinueWith(task => task.IsFaulted
                  ? $"error producing message: {task.Exception.Message}"
                  : $"produced to: {task.Result.TopicPartitionOffset}");
      }
    }
  }
```

In the above code, `ProduceAsync(topicName, new Message<string, ProductRangeEvent> { Key = null, Value = kafkaEvent })` value = kafkaEvent is giving error. This kafkaEvent is of type ProductRangeEvent. It is giving me error cannot implicitly convert type T to ProductRangeEvent. 
I am calling above method as

```
public class TestController
  {
    private readonly IKafkaProducer kafkaProducer;

    public TestController(IKafkaProducer kafkaProducer)
    {
      this.kafkaProducer = kafkaProducer;
    }
     [HttpGet]
        [Route("/api/test")]
        public IActionResult Test()
        {
          ProductRangeEvent productRangeEvent = new ProductRangeEvent
          {
            id = "101"
          };
          var response = this.kafkaProducer.ProduceAsync(productRangeEvent, "users");
          response.Wait();
          var hi = response.IsCompletedSuccessfully;
          return null;
        }
      }
```

In the above code  private readonly IKafkaProducer kafkaProducer; is also giving me error Using the generic type IKafkaProducer requires one argument. 
Can someone help me to fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need a constraint `where T : ProductRangeEvent` if you want your generic type to match.  Otherwise you need to change the code to be more generic in the use of the generic type.  As for the other error you have to specify the generic type `IKafkaProducer<ProductRangeEvent>`

Comment: Thanks where T : ProductRangeEvent where should I add? interface or class?

Comment: @Niranjan  on both

Comment: I added and error gone in class implementation. But error remains in my controller class.

Comment: @Niranjan refresh page. juharr edited his comment to solve second error

Comment: @Niranjan also controller action should be made async and not use blocking call `Wait()`

Comment: Thanks I made   private readonly IKafkaProducer<ProductRangeEvent> kafkaProducer; and started workig fine.

Comment: @juharr you should consider adding an answer. note my comment about async controller action. Happy coding.

Comment: I changed to public async Task<IActionResult>. Then  var response = await this.kafkaProducer.ProduceAsync(productRangeEvent, "users"); added await. This gives me result cannot assign void to implicitly typed variable

Comment: @Niranjan you interface had `Task` which is same as void. it wont return anything when awaited

Comment: remove `response` and just await

Comment: Thanks I have fixed it. Can we add multiple models Like IKafkaProducer<ProductRangeEvent, LsplTimephaseEvent>?

Comment: would need to redefine the interface or create additional ones

Comment: Need to redefine so that I can send multiple types

Comment: clarify what you mean when you say multiple types. the generic interface/class allows you to change the generic argument so you can use other types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
private readonly IKafkaProducer kafkaProducer;
```

To

```
private readonly IKafkaProducer<ProductRangeEvent> kafkaProducer;
```

Comment: Thanks If we want more than one type we need to send in same class then can we make like this IKafkaProducer<ProductRangeEvent, LsplTimephaseEvent>